# What's the meaning of "looked up from his sandwich" in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> "Her putting that eagle in the stable all night," Dunbar said. "Ain't she afeared of some fox or other varmint getting it?"
>
> Ross **looked up from his sandwich** and nodded at the dead snake.
>
> "If it can handle a boss rattler like that one it can handle anything on four legs or even two if it come to that. I'd no more strut up and tangle with that eagle than I'd tangle with the one what can tame such a critter," Ross concluded.
>
> Source: [Serena](https://ronrashserena.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/rash_ron-serena.pdf) by Ron Rash

This paragraph was in an exam.

Comment: What *specifically* don't you understand? (About the *sentence*, not paragraph.) People often look ***down*** at their food while they're eating it, so looking "away" at something else would normally involve looking ***up***.

Comment: Actually *looked up* could mean to search for and find in a text, index, etc.  The phrase @Fateme needs to understand is, *Looked up **from***.  You can *look up* the phrase *looked up from* in any online dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Ross was eating his sandwich and looking at it while he was eating. Then, he looked up (in other words he stopped looking at the sandwich) and nodded at the snake)...

Comment: How is this an answer??